# Download to root directory

Tags: vb.net, directory, root

Okay, so I have been searching for ages to find this but no luck.

I am using:

```
Me.downloader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(fileUrl), Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), Stopwatch.StartNew)
```

To download a file but I want it to save to the root directory of my program in a file called launcher.

So for example, if my program is on the desktop and I open it and click start I want it to create the launcher folder if it's missing then download the files into that and if it's not then just download the files into it.

I've  been looking everywhere to find code which would allow me to do this and I have tried lots of different things.

At the moment, it justs saves in the root directory of where the program is.

Thanks.

Comment: Need to know what operating system you are using and how the program was installed.  Newer OS's do not allow writing in the program folder and instead force you to write into the ProgramData folder for your application, or the user data space.  This is primarily because apps no longer have administrative access like they did in XP and prior versions of windows.

Comment: I am making a program in vb.net and I am using windows 7, program should work on all operating systems.

Comment: Windows 7 will not allow app to write in program directory unless it is run as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim baseDir As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Dim launcherDir As String = Path.Combine(baseDir, "Launcher")

If Not Directory.Exists(launcherDir) Then
   Directory.CreateDirectory(launcherDir)
End If

Dim targetFile = Path.Combine(launcherDir, Path.GetFileName(fileUrl))

Me.downloader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(fileUrl), targetFile, Stopwatch.StartNew)
```

Comment: Sweet, it works. Thank you very much. I assume you wrote the code quickly as there were a few bugs. You wrote 'Dim laucherDir but used the variable 'launcherDir which confused me at first but then I saw that it was a typo. Also Create isn't a part of Directory and I had to change that to Directory.CreateDirectory. Other than that, this works great, thank you for your time.